# Keras InceptionV3 TypeError: unhashable type: 'Dimension'

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to implement a model which will take grayscale images as input and return a numeric value as output. I am using InceptionV3 (training from scratch) as feature extractor and then using some dense layers for the regression for the last stages.

Here is my code:

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.layers import Input, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dense, Dropout, Flatten, BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Model
from keras.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from keras.utils import plot_model

inputs = Input(shape=(256, 256, 1))
x = BatchNormalization()(inputs)
x = InceptionV3(include_top = False, weights = None, input_shape=inputs.shape[1:])(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(1000, activation = 'relu' )(x)
x = Dense(1000, activation = 'relu' )(x)
outputs = Dense(1, activation = 'linear' )(x)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mse', metrics = [mae])

model.summary()
```

Now I am getting this error when I run the code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-50041eb640cc> in <module>()
      7 inputs = Input(shape=(256, 256, 1))
      8 x = BatchNormalization()(inputs)
----> 9 x = InceptionV3(include_top = False, weights = None, input_shape=inputs.shape[1:])(x)
     10 x = BatchNormalization()(x)
     11 x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_applications/imagenet_utils.py in _obtain_input_shape(input_shape, default_size, min_size, data_format, require_flatten, weights)
    273             default_shape = (input_shape[0], default_size, default_size)
    274         else:
--> 275             if input_shape[-1] not in {1, 3}:
    276                 warnings.warn(
    277                     'This model usually expects 1 or 3 input channels. '

TypeError: unhashable type: 'Dimension'
```

I don't understand what is causing the error because it was absolutely fine when I was using sequential model. But it is not working for this functional model.

Comment: check your `input_shape=inputs.shape[1:]`,it does not seem right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inputs.shape` is not a list, hence it is throwing error. It gives you shape with type `tensorflow.python.framework.tensor_shape.TensorShape` which has a list of each dimension with type `Dimension`

```
print(inputs.shape)
# output TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(256), Dimension(256), Dimension(1)])
```

You can use `as_list()` to get shapes as list:

```
# inputs.shape.as_list()
# output [None, 256, 256, 1]

x = InceptionV3(include_top = False, weights = None, input_shape=inputs.shape.as_list()[1:])(x)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. I got confused because when I printed `inputs.shape` the output was `(?,256,256,1)`. So I thought it was a tuple.